# Counts where more than one column is true

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 7 true/false columns, how can I select ALL rows that have 2 or more of the columns set to true?

Here is what I have so far:

```
select count(*), c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
from members
where
1 in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A true/false column is just a 1 digit integer.  Unless you have values other than 0 and 1 stored or the column is nullable, you can just add the columns and check whether the result is >= 2

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 >= 2
```

If there are some non-0 and non-1 entries, you should correct this beforehand.  If they can be NULL, you'll need to use `WHERE IFNULL(c1, 0)...`

Answer (score 3):

You could try following:

SELECT * FROM members WHERE c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6+c7>=2

Answer (score 1):

Since true is 1, you can calculate the total of the fields to be more => 2.

`SELECT * FROM members WHERE c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6+c7 >= 2`